# How to capture routing event of anchor tag

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I need to save users's browsing history while they using the app so I capturing router events to store the urls like the code below. It work with routing inside the app, but when it come to `<a href="/example" target="_blank">` no event fired. How do I capture it's event ?

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
).subscribe( // My logics to store the URL )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [routerLink], not href, and it will capture the navigationEnd.

If you have to use `target=_blank`, perhaps try logging the navigation in the ngOnInit of the component that is navigated to in the new tab.

Comment: No, that will open the link in a new tab, which won't send the NavigationEnd event back to your subscription, because the entire app will reload to the link in the new tab, creating another session.

Comment: Well, the thing is the existing behavior of the app required some link to have it as it is, some link open to a completely different pages or apps, that why I am asking about capturing, since remove `target="_blank"` (or the behavior) is not an option I have.